# HTML5: [video] vs <video>

Tags: wordpress, html, video

I'm seeing this bit of HTML5, from a Wordpress document:

```
[video width="792" height="406" mp4="blahblah"][/video]
```

When I change it to this:

```
<video width="792" height="406" mp4="blahblah"></video>
```

The video doesn't show.  Any doc I've been able to find (such as [the W3Schools doc](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)) on the video tag uses the usual `<video>` syntax.  What's up with this alternative syntax?

Comment: First bit code are basically Wordpress [Shortcodes](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/wordpress-shortcodes-complete-guide/)

Comment: @DejoDekic So not only does Wordpress have a library of these, you can write your own.  Interesting.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello the first syntax you show, is shortcode which only works in Wordpress for embedding videos, example:

```
[video mp4="source.mp4" ogv="source.ogv" webm="source.webm"]
```

Documentation for that can be found here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Video_Shortcode

HTML5 Video tags on the other hand which is part of a specification, you could use to embed a video on webpage that is not wordpress, that for example would look like this:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

For more examples you can look here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

For the full HTML5 video specification you can look here:https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/video.html

Comment: "Shortcode" in Wordpress.  I'll remember that.  Thank you!